# Compliing C++ CGAL Module that is callable from Python

Tags: c++, python, cgal

I am trying to compile some C++ code that is to be called from Python and then calls CGAL.

I need to be able to specify some flags on compilation, but not sure how to do this as the build process is

```
./CGAL-4.2/scripts/cgal_create_CMakeLists -s CallGCAL

cmake -DCGAL_DIR=./CGAL-4.2 .

make
```

And I don't want to have to hand edit the Makefile or CMakeLists

The error message I get from above without Flags to tell gcc it need Python are

```
CMakeFiles/CallGCAL.dir/CallGCAL.cpp.o: In function `initmyModule()':
CallGCAL.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `Py_InitModule4'
CMakeFiles/CallGCAL.dir/CallGCAL.cpp.o: In function `py_polygon(_object*, _object*)':
CallGCAL.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
CMakeFiles/CallGCAL.dir/CallGCAL.cpp.o: In function `py_hull(_object*, _object*)':
CallGCAL.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `Py_BuildValue'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay solved!!! Had to pass a variable to cmake.

Working script is as follows.

./CGAL-4.2/scripts/cgal_create_CMakeLists -s CallCGAL

cmake -DCGAL_DIR=./CGAL-4.2 -DCGAL_CXX_FLAGS="-shared -fPIC" .

make

rm -f CallCGAL.so

mv CallCGAL CallCGAL.so

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correctly that want to compile your own code, which uses both Python and CGAL, with the aid of a makefile that comes with CGAL?

That is **obviously impossible**, since the CGAL makefile cannot know about Python. You **must write your own makefile**, which can be based on some existing makefiles, but also knows about Phython. The error you're reporting is generated by the loader which cannot find the Python library to resolve certain symbols. Thus, all you have to add to the makefile are the relevant `-l` and `-L` options.

Comment: Not quite. I want to compile my own code that is called from Python but is written in C++ and calls CGAL. CGAL does not supply a Makefile directly. It provides various scripts that make CMAKEText files that Cmake uses to make a MAkefile. I have since found documentation at http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/installation_manual/Chapter_installation_manual.html#Subsection_16.2 says about various Compiler linker flags but I don't know enough about CMAKE or the CGAL scripts to know where I am supposed to set such variables.

Comment: The manual you refer to is the manual to build the CGAL libraries (and examples and demos). It is not a general manual to build other software using CGAL.

Answer (score 0):

The CMakeLists.txt created by `cgal_create_CMakeLists` is not at all designed for your use case. The created `CMakeLists.txt` tries to compile an executable, whereas you want to create a *module*. In the `CMakeLists.txt`, replace the line:

```
create_single_source_cgal_program(CallCGAL.cpp)
```

by:

```
add_library(CallCGAL MODULE CallCGAL.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CallCGAL ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )
```

That way, CMake will create the correct Makefile, without any need to rename a file, or tweak the compilation and linking flags.

Comment: Thanks but that means when I distribute my code, I would have to have people modify the CGAL script. Think I would prefer just to distribute my compile script even if a bit hacky

Comment: The usual way of doing is to distribute a cross-platform CMakeLists.txt with the code. That is what we do in CGAL.

Comment: Note also that you can build a module using CGAL without configuring it with CMake. But you will have to implement a build system yourself. CMake is just a cross-platform way to create build systems for a given piece of software.